# Bootstrap table overflows from div in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I'm using latest bootstrap 4.0 and have an issue with overflowing table in Chrome browser.

[image]

In Firefox it scales correctly:
[image]

I have been trying several tricks and tips, but no luck. I wonder if it is some bug in Chrome actually?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="titled-container-header">
        Täiendkoolitused - Standardolukorrad
    </div>
    <div class="titled-container-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                <table class="table table-responsive table-secondary">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="label">Koolitusele pääsemise tingimused</td>
                        <td>Koolitus on mõeldud treeneritele,kelle treenitavad võistkonnad mängivad 11v11.

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="label">Info</td>
                        <td>Koolitus on mõeldud vähemalt EJL C litsentsi treeneritele, kelle treenitavad võistkonnad mängivad 11v11.
                            <br>
                            <br>Räägime standardolukordade tähtsusest jalgpallis -filosoofiad, trendid ja mängijate treenimise ning õpetamise
                            võimalustest.
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td class="label">Vabu kohti</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto pad-left">

                    <table class="table-bordered table-responsive table-primary">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="address">Elukoha aadress</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="address" name="address">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="phone">Telefon</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="email">Email</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="invoice_name">Arve saaja nimi</label>
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id="invoice_name" name="invoice_name">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example uses Bootstrap alpha. Does the problem exist in beta?

Comment: Tried with latest beta - same thing